# Perché non si può usare la forma dell'imperativo della seconda persona singolare con una negazione?

Tags: verbs, etymology, history, tenses

La negazione di un imperativo nella seconda persona plurale si fa semplicemente aggiungendo "non" prima del verbo coniugato all'imperativo. Ecco un esempio che ho tratto del libro  *Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri* di Federica Colombo:

> **Non prendete** appuntamenti per lunedì!

Anche per le forme mancanti dell'imperativo in cui si ricorre al cosiddetto "congiuntivo esortativo", la negazione si fa semplicemente aggiungendo "non" prima del verbo in congiuntivo. A continuazione elenco alcuni esempi dallo stesso libro:

> - Signora, **non parli** con il direttore. La aiuto io!
> - **Non dormiamo!** Ci sono molte cose da fare!
> - Signori, **non prendano** questa strada!

Tuttavia, la negazione di un imperativo alla seconda persona singolare si fa in un modo diverso: si costruisce con il verbo all'infinito preceduto da "non", come in questi esempi dal libro sopra citato:

> - **Non parlare** ad alta voce! Il bambino sta dormendo!  (non si dice "non parla")
> - **Non prendere** la macchina, vieni a piedi! (non si dice "non prendi")
> - Paolo, **non dormire**! (non si dice "non dormi")

C'è qualche ragione di tipo etimologico o di storia della lingua che ci possa far capire perché questo è così?

L'articolo [*Imperativo* della Grammatica italiana Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperativo_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/) non spiega nulla al riguardo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Premetto di non essere un linguista, ma potrebbe derivare dal latino *noli*, imperativo seconda persona singolare del verbo *nolo* ("non volere"). In latino, *noli* richiede l'infinito alla seconda persona singolare, e viene usato per intimare di *non* fare qualcosa.

Un esempio piuttosto famoso è "noli me tangere", che letteralmente significa "non mi toccare". Anche qui abbiamo la forma verbo + infinito quindi.

[Questa pagina](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperativo_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/) del sito Treccani sembrerebbe confermare questa idea, nella sezione **3. Imperativo negativo**:

> Il latino classico aveva quattro possibilità per esprimere l’imperativo negativo:
>
> [...]
>
> (c) l’imperativo *noli* o *nolite* (imperativi di *nolo* «non volere») + infinito (*noli amare*, *nolite amare*);
>
> (d) la negazione *ne* + congiuntivo perfetto (o futuro anteriore), per esprimere una proibizione categorica (*ne amaveris*).

Sempre questo articolo suggerisce che l'evoluzione di *noli* sia una combinazione delle opzioni c) e d):

> l’italiano – come anche il romeno e il francese antico – nell’adoperare la costruzione *non* + infinito per la II persona sing., opera una sorta di fusione tra la terza e la quarta possibilità del latino.

> Grazie all’evoluzione fonetica (perdita della sillaba /ve/, convergenza di -*im*, -*is*, -*it* in /e/), il congiuntivo perfetto dei verbi in -*are* e in -*ire* (coniugazioni più ricche e produttive nel latino volgare) viene a corrispondere, nel singolare, all’infinito: amaverim > amarim > *amare*, amaveris > amaris > *amare(s)*, amaverit > amarit > *amare*; audiverim > audirim > *udire*, audiveris > audiris > *udire*, audiverit > audirit > *udire*. Questo processo fa sì che nella coscienza dei parlanti sia avvertita un’identità dell’imperativo negativo singolare all’infinito, identità che dal gruppo dei verbi regolari viene estesa anche agli altri verbi: ne scripseris > *non scrissere > *non scrivere*; ne feceris > *non fecere > *non facere* > *non fare*. Tale fenomeno risulta già in uno dei primi documenti volgari, l’iscrizione della catacomba di Commodilla: *non dicere ille secreta a bboce* ([...]). Per quanto riguarda il passaggio dalla negazione *ne* alla negazione *non*, può aver influito la terza possibilità del latino: *noli* passa a *non*, perdendo l’espressione del desiderio o del comando: *noli = non (voler)*.

Comment: Ah, ecco! Ricercando su Google *noli imperativo*, ho trovato questo articolo della Treccani in cui si trova qualche riferimento a quello che stai spiegando:  http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperativo_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/. Puoi usarlo per completare questa tua risposta.

Comment: Veramente, della Treccani avevo letto questo articolo, http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperativo_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/. Ma quest'altro mi era proprio sfuggito.

Comment: @Charo Potrebbe sicuramente anche essere una fusione di c) e d). Il "ne" dell'opzione d) potrebbe essere diventato il nostro "non", mantenendo però l'infinito dell'opzione c). Ma mi sembra anche possibile che l'opzione c) si sia semplicemente evoluta da _noli_ a _non_. Immagino possano essere valide entrambe.

Comment: @Charo Risposta aggiornata. Meglio?

Comment: Sì, ottimo, @user1301428!

Comment: Ho aggiunto un altro passo dell'articolo della Treccani. Se non ti sembra bene, però, fai un rollback, per favore.

Comment: Quello che ho appena aggiunto mi sembra anche importante perché si possa capire cosa s'intende per fusione delle opzioni c) e d). Ma se non sei d'accordo, puoi fare un rollback.

Comment: Approvo la modifica :)